# How to get first and last day of month with IntlDateFormatter ( local calendar )

Tags: php, calendar

I want to get first and last day of month with `IntlDateFormatter`

because it supports other calendars (local calendars), so I want to get first day of month in jalali/persian calendar.

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IntlDateFormatter` class is just for formatting days, for working with days in other calendars you want to look at `IntlCalendar`.

By enabling [Lenient Mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intlcalendar.setlenient.php) I think you can use `-1` for the day together with `set` and `current month + 1` for the month value, and get the same behaviour as for mktime. I don't have any idea what a correct date would be like, so I'm not able to test it at the moment. If you add example data to your question it'd be easier to verify a possible solution.